# convert uint8 and uint32 variables to one uint64

Tags: c, bit-shift, uint64, uint8t, uint32

I have the following variables.

```
uint8_t flags;
uint32_t token;
```

I need to write function that cobine them into one uint64_t, and than parse them back into two variables, one of uint8_t and one of uint32_t.

```
uint64 convert(uint8_t flags, uint32_t token);
void convertBack(uint64 allTogether, uint8_t* flags, uint32_t* token);
```

I tried to found something that doing the following, but most of what I found is convert two of the same to one bigger, like two uint32_t to one uint64_t

Thank You

Comment: `(uint64_t)flags ^ !token` would be a combination. Try if it works. If not, you should clarfy what you mean with "combine". That can mean anything!

Comment: Do you want to just store the uint8 and uint32 in a uint64 variable?

Comment: @Olaf: ok, the "combine" part is ambiguous, but it's clear from the rest of the sentence it has to be a two-way transformation (bijection).

Comment: @Groo: That was just an intentionally nonsense example, sorry you did not get it. It still leaves a lot of options (apart from that some minor research effort by OP would have shown at least some way; I'd care less if there was at least **some** code shown - as-is, it is just a request for code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
uint64_t convert(uint8_t flags, uint32_t token)
{
  return ((uint64_t) flags << 32) | token;
}
```

This puts the 8-bit field "above" the 32-bit one, i.e. the returned `uint64_t` has its bits arranged like this:

```
 +---------------------------------+--------------------------------+
 |666655555555554444444444|33333333|3322222222221111111111          |
 |321098765432109876543210|98765432|10987654321098765432109876543210|
 +------------------------+--------+--------------------------------+
 |        unused(24)      |flags(8)|          token(32)             |
 +------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Bit numbers in decimal should be read downwards, bit 0 is on the far right (the LSB).

I'll leave `convertBack()` (which is a pretty bad name, both of these names are sub-optimal) to you. :)

Comment: In the Ascii art above, it seems like `flags` are at the wrong position, at bit 40 (and 10 bits wide).

Comment: @Groo Thanks, I totally screwed that one up. I first "drew" it way simpler, and then messed it up when I changed styles. Fixed now I hope, and also added field withs in parentheses for perhaps 1% more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You may organize the 64bit integer with:

- low 8bit for `flags`,
- following 32bit for `token`

So,

```
uint64_t convert(uint8_t flags, uint32_t token)
{
    return ((uint64_t)token << 8) | flags;
}
```

the convert it back

```
void convertBack(uint64_t allTogether, uint8_t* flags, uint32_t* token)
{
    *flags = allTogether & ~( ~0UL << 8 );
    *token = allTogether >> 8;
}
```